# Direction of unboundedness

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, $ with $0 \leq (x_1+x_2+x_3) \leq 1$ from the two follow equations:

$10 =  12x_1+3.6x_3 $

$39=14x_2+1.4x_3$

With the restriction 
 $0 \leq{x_1, x_2, x_3} \leq1 $

I've tried every way I could think of, but can't find a way to keep $x_1+x_2+x_3 <=1$

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your equations as

$x_1 = \frac{10-3.6x_3}{12},$

$x_2 = \frac{39-1.4x_3}{14}.$

Then I would plug these two expressions (where the right-hand-side contains *only* $x_3$) for $x_1$ and $x_2$ into $x_1+x_2+x_3$. Then you get something that depends only on $x_3$, and you then can choose the set of values for $x_3$ for which $0\leq x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 variable ,and two equation . so : find all of them by one variable ,and put in first relation     for example 
$$x_3=\alpha$$ $$x_1=\frac{10-3.6\alpha}{12}\\x_2=\frac{39-1.4\alpha}{14}\\ 0\leq  \frac{10-3.6\alpha}{12}+\frac{39-1.4\alpha}{14}+\alpha \leq 1$$